# How do I use appbundler for java?

Tags: java, macos, jar

I download the appbundler.jar file from java.net, and I want to bundle a jar file into a Mac OS X app with extension .app.  Can anyone provide me with some beginner advice as to how to use the "appbundler-1.0.jar" file to create a .app, preferably from eclipse?  Thanks!

Comment: http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/technotes/guides/jweb/packagingAppsForMac.html

Comment: There's an updated appbundler fork at https://bitbucket.org/infinitekind/appbundler/overview that you should probably take a look at.